# Can I create a group admin role to have all file permission to files own by its group in a multi-users linux system?

Tags: linux, permissions, file-permissions

There is a shared hpc cluster used by multiple research groups. For each reasearch groups its user accounts will be created under a dedicated group.

Here is the case, there are multiple users in a group, we want to assign permission to one or several users in that group to allow them to have all permissions over files own by the group, so that they can act like admins of the group to do some management jobs.

The major task of group admins is to manage/coordinate data for the team, and provision common configurations for all group member, so all they need is to have rwx permissions to all the files own by the same group.

Is it possible to do this in Linux? If it is possible, how?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's possible, but maybe you could edit the question to clarify. What kind of permissions do the members of the groups need for the files? What kind of tasks should these managers be able to perform other group members can't? The more details you give, the more focused answers you can get.

Comment: Only file permission is needed, the major task of group admins is to manage the data for the team, and provision common configurations for all group member, so all they need is to have rwx permissions to all the files own by the same group.

Comment: Please remember, SE sites aren't discussion forums. Better to add new info by [editing](https://superuser.com/posts/1768731/edit) the question as I now did for you. This way the relevant stuff is immediately available without browsing through comments.